# NestJS custom decorator returns not called

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, backend

I'm trying to implement custom decorator by this way :

```js
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from '../users/entities/user.entity';

export const getCurrentUserByContext = (context: ExecutionContext): User => {
  if (context.getType() === 'http') {
    return context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user;
  }
  if (context.getType() === 'rpc') {
    return context.switchToRpc().getData().user;
  }
};

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (_data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    return getCurrentUserByContext(context);
  },
);
```

Then i invoke it as below :

```js
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('login')
  async login(
    @CurrentUser() user: User,

    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
  ) {
    await this.authService.login(user, response);
    response.send(user);
  }
```

When i try to login , i'm getting the below error

```html
 | [Nest] 43  - 10/03/2022, 8:08:42 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
auth_1               | TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
auth_1               |     at AuthService.login (/usr/src/app/dist/apps/auth/main.js:169:26)
auth_1               |     at AuthController.login (/usr/src/app/dist/apps/auth/main.js:40:32)
auth_1               |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
auth_1               |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
auth_1               |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

After deep investigation, i can see that the function CurrentUser is never invoked (console.log in that CurrentUser function is returning nothing ) .

Replacing @CurrentUser  by only the @Req req -> req.user , eveithing works fine.

So Why the custom decorator is not invoqued ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Any chance, you can create a StackBlits, or GitHub repo with this issue?

Comment: how that `AuthService#login` look like?

Comment: Hi. The github repo is git@github.com:zoutigo/irundo-back.git. It is a docker based installation : npm install -> docker-compose up --build -V  ,  additional infos in the readme.md . Let me know please if you need more infos . Thanks